# I can't get the right rotation of my transform in unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, rotation, character

Hi everyone I have some little problem in Unity 3D. I am trying to do some walking simulation I have character and I have joints while she was walking I want to get the rotation of y. But when I try it I get some results like (transform of rotation in unity is -60 for example the value I get in program 0.059871 something like that how can I read the -60 the right value?)

Comment: Can you show how you try to read the value?

Comment: Post the code you are using to get the rotation now.  This will make sure that you won't get an answer that's doing that exact thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you take the wrong properties, the Quaternion.y is a value from 0 to 1 (CMIIW)
but if you want to get you rotation in degree you can use Vector3.y by taking

```
var y = gameObject.transform.localEulerAngles.y;
```

Also, please attach your code before asking some code related issue

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time have a nice day :)